# How to Create a Voice Chat using Python?

Tags: python, sockets, voice

I'm trying to write a code that allows two computers (on the same network) to voice chat using sockets. I searched everywhere but I can't seem to find a solution. The only solutions I found were using PyAudio and unfortunately I tried to install this library for a long time with no success. It seemed to me like an easy project but after days of research I think that I should just give up. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to easily install PyAudio is to using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) and doing

```
conda install pyaudio
```

I do not know how to make a voice chat with python